# Running SonarQube on Solaris using Jsvc

Tags: sonarqube, solaris

The [SonarQube 5.0 documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+on+AIX%2C+HPUX+or+Solaris) states that in order to install SonarQube on AIX, HPUX or Solaris, one *must* install Java Service Wrapper, which is licensed software.

Is it possible to do this using some free/open source alternative?

There's a [Jsvc](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/jsvc.html) library by Apache that is used to accomplish the same functionality. I wonder if anyone has successfully managed to use it.

Answer (score 1):

We haven't documented it yet, but with SonarQube 5.0+, you can start SonarQube using a simple Java process.

Just open a terminal and run:

```
java -jar <sq_install_dir>/lib/sonar-application-5.0.jar
```

This should allow you to run SonarQube on Solaris without needing to install anything else.