# Running Sonarqube on AIX

Tags: ruby, sonarqube, aix, i18n-gem

Here is my setup

- AIX Version 7.1
- SonarQube 5.1
- Java71_64

I try to start up sonarqube with

```
/usr/java71_64/bin/java -jar ./sonarqube-5.1/lib/sonar-application-5.1.jar
```

all seems good and I get following output:

```
/usr/java71_64/bin/java -jar ./sonarqube-5.1/lib/sonar-application-5.1.jar
2015.05.20 14:55:10 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[search]: /usr/java71_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=/server/sonarqube-5.1/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer /tmp/sq-process8605905139828216720properties
2015.05.20 14:55:22 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[search] is up
2015.05.20 14:55:22 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[web]: /usr/java71_64/jre/bin/java -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djruby.management.enabled=false -Djruby.compile.invokedynamic=false -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=160m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.io.tmpdir=/server/sonarqube-5.1/temp -cp ./lib/common/*:./lib/server/*:/server/sonarqube-5.1/lib/jdbc/h2/h2-1.3.176.jar org.sonar.server.app.WebServer /tmp/sq-process8098035030120374349properties
2015.05.20 14:55:52 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] is up
```

But when i try to open [ip]:9000 in my browser i get:

```
org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException: uninitialized constant I18n
    from org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2689:in const_missing'
    from /server/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record.rb:83:in (root)'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1075:in require'
    from jar:file:/server/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in require'
    from jar:file:/server/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in require'
    from /server/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:1:in (root)'
    from org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in each'
    from /server/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:268:in require_frameworks'
    from /server/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:268:in require_frameworks'
    from file:/server/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:51:in require_frameworks_with_servlet_env'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223:in send'
    from /server/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:134:in process'
    from /server/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:113:in run'
    from org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1094:in load'
    from /server/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:55:in (root)'
    from file:/server/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:1:in (root)'
    from file:/server/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:25:in load_environment'
    at org.jruby.rack.RackInitializationException.wrap(RackInitializationException.java:29)
    at org.jruby.rack.RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.init(RackApplicationFactoryDecorator.java:98)
    at org.jruby.rack.RackServletContextListener.contextInitialized(RackServletContextListener.java:50)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4720)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5154)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1409)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1399)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:274)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1157)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:627)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:809)
Caused by: org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (NameError) uninitialized constant I18n
    at org.jruby.RubyModule.const_missing(org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2689)
    at RUBY.(root)(/server/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/activerecord-2.3.15/lib/active_record.rb:83)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.require(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1075)
    at Kernel.require(jar:file:/server/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55)
    at Kernel.require(jar:file:/server/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar!/META-INF/jruby.home/lib/ruby/shared/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53)
    at RUBY.(root)(/server/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:1)
    at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613)
    at RUBY.require_frameworks(/server/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:268)
    at RUBY.require_frameworks(/server/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:268)
    at RUBY.require_frameworks_with_servlet_env(file:/server/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:51)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.send(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2223)
    at RUBY.process(/server/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:134)
    at RUBY.run(/server/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/gems/gems/rails-2.3.15/lib/initializer.rb:113)
    at org.jruby.RubyKernel.load(org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:1094)
    at RUBY.(root)(/server/sonarqube-5.1/web/WEB-INF/config/environment.rb:55)
    at RUBY.(root)(file:/server/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:1)
    at RUBY.load_environment(file:/server/sonarqube-5.1/lib/server/jruby-rack-1.1.13.2.jar!/jruby/rack/rails/environment2.rb:25)
```

Until now I couldn´t figure out a solution, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you provide the full logs please ? You can use gist.github.com.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/e067aeda55e7e929ed32.git

Comment: https://gist.github.com/alfonssocken/e067aeda55e7e929ed32

Comment: I can't find the reason why JRuby is not correctly initialized. Of course it's impossible for me to reproduce the issue on AIX with IBM JRE. I can only suggest to wait until drop of JRuby (no planned release yet)

Answer (score 0):

First, you must be sure to use a JDK that is compatible with SonarQube. Check this page for more details : http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Requirements
You will see IBM JDK is not supported.
Also by running "java -jar ./sonarqube-5.1/lib/sonar-application-5.1.jar" you are not taken into account all the jar that must be in your classpath to run SQ.
Check conf/wrapper.conf to know which directories must be in your classpath.

Comment: Thank you. Although it is not officially supported, I thought it would be somehow possible to run Sonarqube on AIX.
As stated on [SonarQube 5.0 documentation](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+SonarQube+on+AIX,+HPUX+or+Solaris) one possible way could be JSW, but this is not an option to me.
In this [answer on Stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492366/running-sonarqube-on-solaris-using-jsvc) they say it is possible to run Sonarqube without JSW.
I added _./lib:./lib/*.jar:./lib/jsw/*.jar_ to my classpath, but got the same error again.